# Customizing Form of guest for shipping address

Tags: forms, magento2.4.5, guest-checkout, guest, customization

I can't find the file or the html for guest shipping address. I want to change the telephone input type from input type = text to input type = number. Any suggestion where to find it or how to customize this bug? (To produce this bug, checkout an item without logging in) Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The checkout forms are made with UI components. In order to modify shipping address form you have to extend it with a custom module. Before we go to extending, first you need to know how the UI components are build and rendered (if you don't know please check documentation or other sources). If you got to `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` you can find a node `shipping-address-fieldset` and in his children you can find a `telephone`. If you check other nodes, such as `region_id` you can see they have a `component`, `config/template` and `config/elementTemplate` nodes. So you have two options:

- modify the form via custom `view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` file. In the file you have to create the same path to the `telephone` node as it is in core file, and then change the component or templates.
- create an after plugin on the `getCheckoutConfig()` function of `Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage` class. And modify the array that this functions is returning. The array contains all the data from xml file.

I would recommend the first option.